# AcceptOnceFileListFilter and renaming a file in Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-dsl

I am writing an IntegrationFlow for SFTP, to copy only the latest file in remote directory, to local. I also want to avoid copying the same file twice so I added an `AcceptOnceFileListFilter`.
Unfortunately the remote files come in form of `IGNORED_STRING_1008202211:22:33.csv`, as you see there is a date-time stamp, based on which I determine the latest file, but the colon symbol is not accepted for filenames in Windows, so I had to apply a function to rename it.
Now this messes with the `AcceptOnceFileListFilter`, I've debugged and the original file name is checked once, then it is compared to the modified one (without colons) - so it always gets downloaded again.

```
Sftp.inboundAdapter(sftpSf)
    .filter(new ChainFileListFilter<>() {{
        addFilter(new LatestFileOnly());
        addFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<>());
    }})
    .localFilename(new Function<String, String>() {
        @Override
        public String apply(String s) {
            return s.replaceAll(":", "");
        }
    })
    .autoCreateLocalDirectory(true)
    .remoteDirectory(readRemoteDirectory)
    .deleteRemoteFiles(false)
    .preserveTimestamp(true)
    .localDirectory(new File(localDirectory));
```

and the filter to find the latest file, from its filename:

```
public class LatestFileOnly implements FileListFilter<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> {

    @Override
    public List<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> filterFiles(ChannelSftp.LsEntry[] files) {
        return Arrays.stream(files)
            .max(byParsedDate)
            .map(Collections::singletonList)
            .orElse(Collections.emptyList());
    }

    public final Comparator<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> byParsedDate = Comparator.comparing(
            (ChannelSftp.LsEntry o) -> {
                        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(o.getFilename());
                        if (m.find()) {
                            return LocalDateTime.parse(m.group(0), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMyyyyHH:mm:ss"));
                        }
                        return LocalDateTime.MIN;
            });
}
```

Polling after a couple of re-tries:
[image: file ignored by the filter]

Comment: The `localFilename()` is applied for exactly a local `java.io.File`, not that `ChannelSftp.LsEntry` which your `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` stores for caching. So, it is not clear where is the clash. Would you mind to point to the code where does such a wrong comparison happen?

Comment: I have added screenshots displaying what is happening. It is now even more perplexing as I noticed that on the 2nd polling the `seenSet` is empty

Comment: It is not a second attempt. As you see the first one is indeed a `ChannelSftp.LsEntry`, but the second one is `File`. So, this story is about different `AcceptOnceFileListFilter`. There is a `localFilter()` option which is applied on transferring the remote file to the local dir. Doesn't look like you set it, so by default it has to be a `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter`. Therefore the "second attempt" does not make sense. So, what Spring Integration version do you use?

Comment: Also pay attention that you check against different instances of the `AcceptOnceFileListFilter`, so this is more confusing how the "third attempt" is even possible...

Comment: That's well spotted, I am not sure why this was going to the filter, but another IntegrationFlow (monitoring local files to send to another remote location) was somehow triggering AcceptOnceFileListFilter, even though it never had it added. I've disabled that IntegrationFlow to focus on this problem and updated screenshot - as you see now the problem is the LsEntry ends up in the seenSet every time, so there must be a problem with comparison.
I'm not sure how that's possible or how to fix it

Answer (score 2):

> as you see now the problem is the LsEntry ends up in the seenSet every time

Yes: that's the problem of the `ChannelSftp.LsEntry` and `AcceptOnceFileListFilter`. It doesn't implement a `hashCode()` method, so every single new instance is different from another even if the target file is the same. For this purpose we have an `SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` which really compares file names and their `getAttrs().getMTime()`. See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/file.html#remote-persistent-flf

> (monitoring local files to send to another remote location) was somehow triggering `AcceptOnceFileListFilter`

You said yourself "monitoring", so you probably use over there a `Files.inboundAdapter()`, which really may be configured with the mentioned `AcceptOnceFileListFilter`.